# Visual Studio Resource group project template

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

Morning,

I am about to do a demo using the Azure SDK 2.8 resource group project template:
[image]

I have found a blog post from 2014 here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-resource-manager-2-5-for-visual-studio/

But the new Edit Parameters box is different and I cant work out what to do with "MyWebSitePackageFolder" and "MyWebSitePackageFileName":

[image]

I know they are related to storage:
[image]

But I get an error when doing a new deployment:
[image]

[image]
[image]

I am just creating a web app from the template:
[image]

Any help would be great!

Comment: Hi Russ, I am using Visual Studio 2015 and unable to reproduce the issue you have. I can't find anything related to "MyWebSitePackageFolder" and "MyWebSitePackageFileName" in both ARM template json and param json. What is the exact error you encountered during deployment?

Comment: is my answer somehow related to your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Morning,

I have not been able to come back to this but I would say that the best solution would be to use VS 2015. Obviously 2013 was updated to allow you to do this but 2015, by default, does this with much more ease.

Not really a solution to the 2013 problem but I have the luxury of using 2015.

Answer (score 0):

These parameters are used to deploy the Web Site files along with the Web App Service. This is done via a reference to the web application project in your solution. Apparently the integration with VS2013 seems to be poor, because in VS2017 these fields appear only after a reference to the web application project has been correctly configured.

The following two screens should help in the general case:

1. notice the web application reference properties[image: web application reference properties]
2. ... and the deployment parameters
   [image: deployment properties]

There is a very good Hands-On Lab provided by Microsoft on this topic [here](https://labondemand.com/Event/MSHandsOnLabs/Home), called "DT00154: Authoring ARM Templates with Visual Studio".